# Copy from one workbook to specific sheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I want to create a script which needs to take out 3 different reports. Information from the reports need to be copied over to specific sheets in the main file "Workingfile.xlsm" from where the script is running. 2nd report is based on data extracted from 1st report and 3rd report is based on the date extracted from 2nd report.

Below is the first attempt at first report which is saved as export.xlsx and file is opened.

The steps performed after this need to be:

1. Delete all previous data in specific sheet "EKKO" in the main file "Workingfile.xlsm"
2. Copy over new data from export file to specific sheet "EKKO" in the main file "Workingfile.xlsm"
3. Close export file
4. Copy column B in the specific sheet "EKKO".

The script seems to stuck at this line: y.Sheets("EKKO").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

```
 Sub Button1_Click()        
        
        
       If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
           Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
           Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        End If
        If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
           Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
        End If
        If Not IsObject(SAP_session) Then
           Set SAP_session = Connection.Children(0)
        End If
        If IsObject(WScript) Then
           WScript.ConnectObject SAP_session, "on"
           WScript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"
        End If
        
        
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nze16n"
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_TABLE-LOW").Text = "EKKO"
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_TABLE-LOW").caretPosition = 4
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btnGO").press
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").Text = "CV_TEST"
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").Text = ""
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").SetFocus
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").caretPosition = 0
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[46]").press
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[43]").press
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\Users\admu\Documents\SAP\SAP GUI"
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "export.xslx"
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
        
        
        End Sub
        
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Sub CopyFromExportFile()
        
        
        Dim x As Workbook
        Dim y As Workbook
        
        Set x = Workbooks("export.xlsx")
        Set y = Workbooks("Workfile.xlsm")
        
        

        x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
        y.Sheets("EKKO").Range("A1").ClearContents
        y.Sheets("EKKO").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        
        x.Close
        
        y.Sheets("EKKO").Columns(2).Copy
        
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum to write code for you. You must say what you tried, what prevented you from doing it, and ask a precise question. For more information, see the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry. Question updated.

Comment: Okay so it's about the line with `PasteSpecial` but what does "seems to stuck" mean, precisely, i.e. what happens?

Comment: It seems I had the order of steps wrong...Copy before Clear. This deactivated Copy part so PasteSpecial couldn't be performed.

Comment: Now to what you may think is a very odd question...  When I try to run whole script only first Sub is executed. It doesn’t execute Sub CopyFromExportFile() ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the order wrong...Order need to be `clear` first then `copy` and `paste`...
Also few small adjustment in the code lines were needed.

```
Sub CopyFromExportFile()    

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks("export.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks("Workfile.xlsm")

y.Sheets("EKKO").Cells.Clear

x.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy
y.Sheets("EKKO").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False

x.Close

y.Sheets("EKKO").Columns(2).Copy    

End Sub
```